# Data Type in c# for finding factorial

Tags: c#, types

What is the biggest data type in c# or which data type should I use to find the factorial of 1619. I tried ulong and uint64 but they trimmed my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Is a BigInteger is not very faster but for big numbers is possible to calculate

Here and simple example from MSDN

```
string positiveString = "91389681247993671255432112000000";
string negativeString = "-90315837410896312071002088037140000";
BigInteger posBigInt = 0;
BigInteger negBigInt = 0;

    try 
    {
         posBigInt = BigInteger.Parse(positiveString);
         Console.WriteLine(posBigInt);
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert the string '{0}' to a BigInteger value.", positiveString);
    }
```

I try and my own example and is working

```
string positiveString = "91389681247993671255432112000000";
string negativeString = "-90315837410896312071002088037140000";
BigInteger b = BigInteger.Parse(positiveString);
BigInteger c = BigInteger.Parse(positiveString);
BigInteger d = b * c;

System.Console.WriteLine(d);
System.Console.ReadLine();

// result 835207383860988607360648144841987935757186784078054400000000000
```

Comment: Thanks but VS is showing error when  try to use BigInteger. Do  have to reference any assembly?

Comment: Yeah. First add System.Numerics from reference and then using System.Numerics and then you can use BigInteger

Comment: @AnkurGupta do you fix the problem.Do you add the necessary assembly in your project.

Comment: Yes I am able to Thanks